# Allow node.exe and ignore all other .exe

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to not igore the file
node.exe

but ignore all other .exe files, how can I achieve this?

My code is not working:

```
# Compiled source #
###################
/build/*
!node.exe
*.exe

*.o
*.so
*.com
*.pdb
*.ini
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" ? What happens that is different from what you expect ?

Comment: see @stewe answer, basically node.exe is not included in my code, it is ignored

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reverse the order from:

```
!node.exe
*.exe
```

to:

```
*.exe
!node.exe
```

The last statement "overwrites" the previous.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed, I will accept this answer when I can (time limit)